# How can you have multiple lines or statements inside a C++ pack expansion?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, stdapply, pack-expansion

Suppose that I have some simple code like the one below, which just prints all of the values in a tuple and keeps track of the current iteration.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

using std::cout;

int main() {
    std::tuple<int, double, size_t, unsigned, short, long long, long> my_tuple(7, 4, 1, 8, 5, 2, 9);
    //Can you spot the pattern? :)
    std::apply(
        [](auto&&... current_value) {
            size_t i = 0; //This is only executed once
            ((
                cout << i++ << ", " << current_value << "\n" //This is repeated the length of the tuple
            ), ...);
        }, my_tuple
    );
    return 0;
}
```

If I wanted to, for example, only print the tuple value if the index was greater than 2, how could I do this? I can't simply put an `if` before the `cout` because statements are not allowed (got `[cquery] expected expression` on repl.it).

More generally, how can I do things like multiple lines of code or statements within a pack expansion?

Using a lambda inside works, e.g.

```cpp
std::apply(
    [](auto&&... current_value) {
        size_t i = 0;
        ((
            [&current_value, &i](){
                cout << i << ", " << current_value << "\n";
                ++i;
            }()
        ), ...);
    }, my_tuple
);
```

But I can't imagine that this is is the most efficient (or intended) solution.

Comment: Actually a lambda is probably the best approach. A good C++ compiler will likely be able to inline the lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It reads much better if you declare the lambda separately and then fold over invoking it:

```cpp
auto f = [&](auto& value){
    cout << i << ", " << value << "\n";
    ++i;
};
(f(current_value), ...);
```

You can also use something Boost.Mp11's `tuple_for_each` to avoid a layer of indirection:

```cpp
size_t i = 0;
tuple_for_each(my_tuple, [&](auto& value){
    cout << i << ", " << value << "\n";
    ++i;
});
```

which is a much more direct way of doing such a thing than going through `std::apply`. Even if you don't want to use Boost.Mp11 (and you should want to), this is fairly easy to implement.

---

There was a language proposal for something called *expansion statements* which would make this a first-class language feature. It didn't quite make C++20, but could be in C++23:

```cpp
size_t i = 0;
template for (auto& value : my_tuple) {
    cout << i << ", " << value << "\n";
    ++i;
}
```

Comment: is template for different proposal for the for... syntax or are they unrelated?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl `for ...` got renamed to `template for`.

Comment: but  co_why would somebody do that? :( I really hope it was for parsing reasons and not because people complained that only 3 dots are not obvious enough...

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl As you can see in my use above, there is no pack. So why choose a syntax based on packs?

Comment: depends on what ... means to you, for me it means something with a list of types(pack, variant), not just pack. Although I would probably prefer  for(auto& value :  my_tuple...) syntax, but that might make grammar unhappy.

Comment: Barry I know how much is opinion of one guy in a random comment important to wg21, but I realized why I hate the typename for (auto& value   )syntax(beside syntax spam): auto already means template(for loop will work on any range).

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl It's not a question of what `...` means to _me_ but what rather what it manes to C++: which is either varargs or a pack, neither of which is what we're dealing with here. Also, `auto` doesn't mean `template` at all?

Comment: Barry - for(auto& x: container) in my head is the same thing as std::for_each(container, [](auto& x){}), and for_each is templated function that takes a templated functor.   note:here I am pretending for_each works on containers, idk what is the matching range version, so I used std::for_each.